How to use transparent shader so mist pass won't show on crow feathers
I am rendering a scene in Blender with mist pass enabled. The scene has two crow characters that have feathers with a semi transparent shader. But since I have the mist pass on, the feather end up having mist on them too which looks really weird. I tried playing with the alpha threshold value under Passes > Data but it didn't help.
What can I do to fix this? Can I not use any sort of transparent shader with mist pass? 

Hello you can put a ColorRamp to control the mist depth

Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "this","issue with" or "question about". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See "What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
